# Google Apps Script: Copy and Paste Formulas Only

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to copy and paste Formulas only in a spreadsheet using Google Apps Script

```
var range = activeSheet.getRange(targetRow-1, 1, 1, activeSheet.getLastColumn());
range.copyTo(activeSheet.getRange(targetRow, 1, 1, activeSheet.getLastColumn()), {contentsOnly:false});
```

This give me the full information, including the formulas and data. However, I wish to only copy the formulas (without data).

`CopyFormulasToRange` unfortunately does not exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following function will copy formulas only.  It has user settings for what row and column to start getting the formulas from.

```
function copyFormulas() {
  var activeSheet,numberOfSourceColumnsToGet,sourceColumnStart,sourceFormulas,sourceRange,
      sourceRowStart,targetColumn,targetRange,targetRowStart;

  //USER INPUT

  sourceRowStart = 1; //Row to start getting formulas from
  sourceColumnStart = 2; //Column to start getting formulas from
  numberOfSourceColumnsToGet = 1; //Number of columns to get formulas from

  targetRowStart = 1; //Row to start copying formulas to
  targetColumn = 3; //Column to start copying formulas to

  //END OF USER INPUT

  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sourceRange = activeSheet.getRange(sourceRowStart, sourceColumnStart, activeSheet.getLastRow(), numberOfSourceColumnsToGet);

  sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulas();//Get only formulas from the source range

  targetRange = activeSheet.getRange(targetRowStart,targetColumn,sourceFormulas.length,sourceFormulas[0].length);

  targetRange.setFormulas(sourceFormulas);//Copy the formulas to the target range
}
```

Comment: It seems that the formulas are not extended; Like with the "pull formulas down" of excel

Comment: Dear @Alan Wells how to copy paste formulas with automatic auto expanding function when a form is submitted?

Comment: To learn how to run a function when a Google Form is submitted, please read the documentation at the following link: [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: This function doesn't update the copied formula to reference cell values in the new row.  All of the references stay the same, referring to cells in the row that the formulas were coped from.  Maybe there are cases where you want this, but the more usual case, it seems to me, is to want the new formulas to refer to values in cells of the new row.  I added an answer that does this while copying only cells containing formulas.

Answer (score 16):

Use getFormulasR1C1 and setFormulasR1C1 to copy formulas and preserve relative references. For example:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var currentRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 3, 1, 4);
  var sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulasR1C1();

  currentRow++;

  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 3, 1, 4);
  targetRange.setFormulasR1C1(sourceFormulas);
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformular1c1
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasr1c1formulas

Comment: This solution didn't work for me because it does a copy for every column, even ones that don't contain formulas.  I don't quite understand why this is a problem, but it wreaked havoc in my case.  I think it had to do with the fact that I have formulas that write into other columns than just the column they are in.  I had to write a function that was more selective, copying only the formulas.  I have added that as another answer.  I appreciate this answer though, as it gave me a starting point for mine.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while trying to figure out how to copy just the formulas from one row into another row.  This is the very common pattern of adding a row to a spreadsheet to add another data set, where each set is a single row and some of the columns in that row are computed values.  You want all of copied formulas to reference values in the new row, not the row from which the formulas were copied.

@AllenWell's answer copies the formulas, but for me at least, doesn't update the cell references to reference cells in the new row.  With his code, the copied formulas still refer to the row from which the formulas were copied.  I have since learned that the secret here is to use `get/setFormulasR1C1` rather than `get/setFormulas` because the latter uses relative references such that formulas reference values in whatever row they're in.

@MarkBird's answer uses `get/setFormulasR1C1` but doesn't work for me.  It seems to put something in every cell of the new row because it does a copy even for columns that do not contain formulas.  This screws up my logic, where I have formulas that put results in multiple columns, but only if they're blank.  His code could work fine in simpler cases, but it would be better if it only copied formulas.  That's what my solution does.

I wrote a more complex function that copies only the formulas in such a way that the formulas reference values in the new row.  I grab all the formulas and then selectively copy them to the new row, skipping empty spots in the list of formulas.  This gave me the behavior I wanted and I think what most people want when they want to create a new row in a spreadsheet.  Here is the function that does this.  it takes a `Sheet` reference and the indexes of the source and destination rows:

```
function copyFormulas(sheet, sourceRow, targetRow) {
    var formulas = sheet.getRange(sourceRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getFormulasR1C1()[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
      if (formulas[i] !== '') {
        sheet.getRange(targetRow, i + 1).setFormulaR1C1(formulas[i]);
      }
    }
}
```

Notice the test for if the formula is empty.  I think this is what is missing from @MarkBird's simpler solution.