# Copy non-empty Range from one tab, and paste at end of another tab, and copy down formulas to the right of the paste range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I used this to copy the non-empty cells from One tab (CopyFromTab), to another tab (PasteToTab). 
However, when it adds new rows to the PasteToTab... ***the formulas to the right of the pasted content (on the PasteToTab) do not copy down (on the PasteToTab).***

**Is there a way for this to Copy Formulas down in new rows on the PasteToTab (these formulas that need to be copied down are in cells to the right that use the data from the pasted content)**

```
function CopyNotEmptyToDifferentTab(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CopyFromTab");  //Copy from here
var range = ss.getRange(8,11,10,6);     //You should be using .getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)

  var nonEmpty = range.getValues().filter(function(row) {           // filter matrix for rows
        return row.some(function(col) { // that have at least one column
          return col !== "";});});      // that is not empty



  if (nonEmpty) {

    var sh2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PasteToTab"); //Paste here

    sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1, nonEmpty.length, nonEmpty[0].length).setValues(nonEmpty);
  } }
```

REFERENCE:
[Copy non-empty range into new sheet, and drag down formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909877/copy-non-empty-range-into-new-sheet-and-drag-down-formulas)

---

**THIS IS THE WORKING SCRIPT THAT:  ADDS ROWS TO BOTTOM OF PASTE SHEET, PASTES DATA FROM COPYFROM SHEET, AND COPIES DOWN FORMULAS.**. THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP @Stykes

```
function CopyNotEmptyToDifferentTab(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CopyFromTab");  //Copy from here

var range = ss.getRange(8,11,10,6);     //You should be using .getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)

  var nonEmpty = range.getValues().filter(function(row) {           // filter matrix for rows
        return row.some(function(col) { // that have at least one column
          return col !== "";});});      // that is not empty

  if (nonEmpty) {


    var sh2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PasteToTab"); //Paste here
   var lastRowNumber= sh2.getLastRow();  //GETS LAST ROW AS VARIABLE
    sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1, nonEmpty.length, nonEmpty[0].length).setValues(nonEmpty);

    var sourceRange = sh2.getRange(lastRowNumber,7,1,6);  //You should be using .getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)

sourceRange.autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);



  } }
```

Comment: Hello!Can you share an example of the Sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: [autoFillToNeighbor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#autoFillToNeighbor(AutoFillSeries))

```
   //range you would like to copy down can be one cell or multiple
   var sourceRange = sheet.getRange("B1:B4");

   // Results in B5:whereeverColumnAEnds 
  sourceRange.autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
```

The range created must include the last row that has the formula. For the code above, if B5 has a formula in it, this code will not work. Instead the range would need to be "B1:B5" or just "B5"

Comment: Thanks - I tried this but did not work....    rangeToPaste=sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1, nonEmpty.length, nonEmpty[0].length);
    rangeToPaste.setValues(nonEmpty);  
rangeToPaste.autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);

Comment: What is the error message you get? I think the last line of code should not start with "rangeToPaste" That is the range you just pasted into. You want the formulas in the next column to copy down.

Comment: Thanks, there is no error message. It just doesn't copy the neighbor's formulas to the right.   It DOES create new rows and paste the content into the new rows.  It DOES NOT copy down the neighboring cell's formulas.  e.g. =iferror(vlookup($I4,'List'!$A$2:$M,12,false)) should be copied down.

Comment: let's say "=iferror(vlookup($I4,'List'!$A$2:$M,12,false))" is in cell B2. sheet.getRange("B2").autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);

Comment: Thanks, I tried this:    sh2.getRange("H3:R3").autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);      to get the formulas from H:R to try to copy down... No success.  Am I taking your suggestion wrong?

Comment: It looks like autoFillToNeighbor is to drag down automatic calculations/count ups... not to drag formulas down?

Comment: I set up an example script in StykesTech.gs function named StykesFunk. It does what I believe you're looking for. I'm a little confused by your examples and their placement on the tabs. in order for this to work, you will need the column directly to the left of the formulas to be populated with data. If that's a dealbreaker, there are other ways, but they will be a little less simple.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The data is just dummy data and formulas in a location.  Your example does work. But I can't get it to pull more complicated formulas down...

Comment: That's very odd. Well you can always use this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130809/google-apps-script-copy-and-paste-formulas-only?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for help -- I clarified the dummy data.  Does it make more sense what trying to do?

Comment: So with that Dummy data, TestStkesFunk  works now. It copies down the data.

Comment: Thanks - I tried it and it does work... until I use the CopyNotEmptyToDifferentTab() function and add new rows.  I also tried to call your function within CopyNotEmptyToDifferentTab() and tried to run it separately.  It doesn't work on the new rows?

Comment: Okay, the problem is that you need the sourceRange variable to include the last row that has formulas in order for the formulas to copy down. You can do this a couple ways: 1. delete all formulas except the top row and then paste them all down again. 2.dynamically select the range so it always includes the last row of formulas.

Comment: Thanks! I see that now.     var sourceRange = sh2.getRange("G##:K##") ... Is that as simple as GetLastRow ?

Comment: Probably not, because your last row for this sheet will be the row with the newly pasted data.

Comment: If you want help with that part, please create another post and mark this one as solved. I am willing to work on that one, so long as it's a new post.

Comment: Wohoo, that worked. Thanks!  Will add cleaned up code.  Still somewhat new to Stack if you want to post answer.. I think you get rep points?